# Google showing website inner search engine results, how does it work?

Tags: search-engine, seo

Sometimes when I search in Google, appears a website and just below... several links from that website. Sometimes also (I don't know if it's related) I click on a result and the website shows me the page with the search terms highlighted.

How does that work? I mean, which technology or standard do I have to implement in my website in order to archieve those effects?

Thanks

Comment: The admins here aren't very helpful for a help site, I'll grant that this is off topic, but can't someone recommend a better stackexchange site for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean sitelinks?

Google's systems analyse the link structure of your site to find shortcuts that will save users time and allow them to quickly find the information they're looking for.

They only show sitelinks for results when they think they'll be useful to the user.

You can read more here http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

**EDIT**

To answer your question, all you can do is make sure you have a well formed site with clear navigation which your users can use and find useful. If your site popular then Google will do the rest.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering if I should provide a special site map or something, but I see that it's just a Google thing.

Comment: well i disagree, google does not analyse the link structure for sitelinks, it's analyses the navigation path of the users. as there is a high correlation of sitelinks and what visitors clicked that searched for the brand of that website.

Comment: @Franz: You would have to argue that one with Google as that quote is directly from their site.

Answer (score 1):

**Google shows highlighted search terms on its cached pages**

When you're viewing a cached result the page is stored on Google's servers - so they can modify as they wish (highlighting search terms).

If you're viewing them on actual websites this is due to either:

- Google wrapper around the page (such as mobile viewing)
- Google toolbar (or similar)